# using aggregation in Javascript function with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using Javascript to do queries to mongodb shell, I have the following function:

```
function myFunction(dbName, colName, name)
{
    var col = db.getSiblingDB(dbName).getCollection(colName);   
    col.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {title: name}},
        {$group: 
           {_id : "$name",
           likes: {$sum: "$likes"}}
        }
    ] );
}
```

the document looks as follows:

```
`{ "title" : "NoSQL", "likes" : 400 }
 { "title" : "MongoDB", "likes" : 100 }
 { "title" : "MongoDB", "likes" : 150 }
 { "title" : "MongoDB", "likes" : 50 }
 { "title" : "Neo4j", "likes" : 50 }
 { "title" : "Neo4j", "likes" : 150 }
 { "title" : "Neo4j", "likes" : 250 }`
```

When I call the function in the mongodb shell, I do not receive output however. I call it like this:

```
myfunction("myDb", "myCol", "Neo4j")
```

Before I do this I do load the Javascript file using the load() function.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: `var output = col.aggregate(...); return output;` ? You need to remember the difference between using a REPL and functional programming. This is not just going to "print" like it does in REPL mode. You need to `return` something from the function you are calling, just as the REPL is basically doing on `col.aggreggate()` just entered on one line.

Comment: Thanx for you helped that worked, I was not aware it had to be done like that.